# UIRefreshController Ending Animation Issue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uirefreshcontrol

When I call for `self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()` it snaps the tableView back to it original spot like it should. How should I go about animating it so that it fluently returns to its original spot on `endRefreshing()`?

Comment: I Have this problem and the unique solution that I found is to call the reloadData with a delay, after the endRefreshing. 

[self.tableView performSelector:@selector(reloadData) withObject:self.tableView afterDelay:0.2];

Comment: @user1715438, me too, afterDelay works for me, this is the only solution.

Comment: Next time, try to provide some of the code to which there is a problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To anyone having this issue, you must call your `endRefreshing` method before you reload the table data. Otherwise when the table updates it will override the refresher and cause it to look buggy.

Comment: "endRefreshing" Must be explicitly called when the refreshing has completed

Answer (score 14):

Try this

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
    // reload tableView after refresh control finish refresh animation
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}];

[self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
[CATransaction commit];
```

Answer (score 3):

I was having this issue and tried every suggestion above (and others from similar threads).

What the problem turned out to be in my case was... I hadn't enabled refreshing in interface builder.  I only added the code to create a refresh control and listen for the value changed event. It worked, but was "jumpy" as others have described.

Enabling it in interface builder fixed my problem.  If you've tried everything else, check your storyboard!

[image: Enable Refreshing in your storyboard!]

Answer (score 2):

```
// stop refreshing
[self.refreshControl endRefreshing];

// update tableview
[self.tableview performSelector:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil afterDelay:.3];
```

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this issue as well. For `endRefreshing()` The documentation states:

> If animations are also enabled, the control is hidden using an animation.

I wrap the call in a UIView animation block and the transition becomes smooth:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) {
    self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me with **Swift 2**

```
if self.refreshControl.refreshing {
     self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}

GlobalHelper.setTimeout(0.1, block: {
     self.tableView.reloadData()
})
```

> this is my timeout function:

```
static func setTimeout(delay:NSTimeInterval, block:()->Void) -> NSTimer {
    return NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(delay, target: NSBlockOperation(block: block), selector: #selector(NSOperation.main), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In Swift 3  iOS 10, I got a similar approach as ibrahimyilmaz and here it is:

```
self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
//Need to dispatch the alertView, otherwise, RefreshControl.endRefreshing() doesn't work.
let when = DispatchTime.now() + 1 
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) { [weak self] in
  self?.showSettingAlertView()
}
```

At first I was dispatching the endRefreshing as proposed in many threads but in fact it's the other way around that works for me.

Additional info: This code is executed in the location:didChange: delegate, not in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear.
Going through other threads, It seems that there is an issue in the Apple SDK when you try to endRefreshing AND try to show a popup at the same time.