# UIRefresh control endRefreshing doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, uirefreshcontrol

When refresh control is triggered by swiping the tableview down, if there is no internet connection, a alert is shown and the refresh control is expected to end refreshing but it doesn't end refreshing even added in main thread

```
class JobsForCategoryVC: UIViewController {
    //MARK:-Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var jobTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    //MARK:-Properties
    var refreshControl:UIRefreshControl!
    var jobCategory:JobCategoryDB!
    var pageNumber:Int = 1
    var downloadMore:Bool = true
    var jobs = [JobModel]()


    //MARK:-LifeCycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupView()
        freshDownload()
    }

    func setupView(){

        refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Loading fresh Jobs")
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.freshDownload), for: .valueChanged)
        jobTableView.addSubview(refreshControl)     

    }

    func freshDownload(){
        pageNumber = 1
        downloadMore = true
        downloadJobsFrom(top: true)
    }


    func downloadJobsFrom(top:Bool){
        if !refreshControl.isRefreshing && top{
            activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        }


        let url = URLStringList.getSearchCategoryJobString(pageNumber: pageNumber, categoryId: jobCategory.id!)

        if let url = URL(string: url){
            Alamofire.request(url, method: .get).responseJSON { (response) in

                if response.result.isSuccess{
                    let json = response.result.value

                    let model = Mapper<JobModel>().mapArray(JSONArray: json as! [[String : Any]])

                    if model?.count == 0{
                        self.downloadMore = false
                    }
                    if let jobs = model{
                        if top{
                              self.jobs = jobs
                        }else{
                            self.jobs += jobs
                        }

                        self.jobTableView.reloadData()
                        self.pageNumber += 1
                    }
                    self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
                    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()

                }else{

                    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                        self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
                        self.jobTableView.reloadData()
                    })

                    if top{
                        showInternetConnectionAlert(viewController: self, activityIndicator: self.activityIndicator, completion: nil)
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    }
}


extension JobsForCategoryVC:UITableViewDataSource{

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if jobs.count > 0 {
            jobTableView.backgroundView = nil
            let cellCount = jobs.count + ((jobs.count-1)/(AdForNumberOfCells-1)) + 1
            return cellCount
        }

        jobTableView.backgroundView =  Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("PullToRefreshView", owner: nil, options: nil)?.first as? PullToRefreshView
        return 0
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row % AdForNumberOfCells  == 0{
            if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "JobsAdTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? JobsAdTableViewCell{
                cell.controller = self
                return cell
            }

        }else{

            if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "JobsTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? JobsTableViewCell{
                 let index = NSIndexPath(item: indexPath.row-(indexPath.row/AdForNumberOfCells)-1, section: 0)
                cell.configure(job: jobs[index.row])
                return cell
            }

        }

        return UITableViewCell()
    }

}

extension JobsForCategoryVC:UITableViewDelegate{


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let webView = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WKWebVC") as? WKWebVC{
            if indexPath.row % AdForNumberOfCells == 0 {
                return
            }
            let index =  NSIndexPath(item: indexPath.row-(indexPath.row/AdForNumberOfCells)-1, section: 0)

            if let urlString = jobs[index.row].url{
                webView.url = urlString
                webView.titleString = jobs[index.row].title
                present(webView, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == self.jobs.count - 1 && downloadMore{
            downloadJobsFrom(top: false)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple way of doing this is

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
     self.jobTableView.reloadData()
     self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
     self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
     self.refreshControl.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: true)

})
```

Comment: That is good answer but in wrong approach.Take a look : https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uirefreshcontrol/1624848-endrefreshing

Comment: @ak2g I believe you meant to say `self.jobTableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: true)` instead of the `UIRefreshControl` calling `setContentOffset` as `UIRefreshControl` doesn't have such a function to call.

Answer (score 4):

Set `UITableView contentOffset` to `zero`

In **Swift 3.0**

```
refreshControl.endRefreshing()
self.yourTableView.contentOffset = CGPoint.zero
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add all UI procedures in the main thread.

The Success block => Turn your code into :

```
if let jobs = model{
     if top{
        self.jobs = jobs
     }else{
        self.jobs += jobs
     }
     self.pageNumber += 1                       
}

DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
     self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
     self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
     self.jobTableView.reloadData()
})
```

And the Fail Block :

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
     self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
     self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
     self.jobTableView.reloadData()
})
```

No matter success or failure,all your UI Progress must included in the main thread.I think you forgot to include the UI Changes inside main thread in Success Block.Or you can do like that,

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .get).responseJSON { (response) in
     if response.result.isSuccess{
          ...
     }else{
          ...
     }
     DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
          self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
          self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
          self.jobTableView.reloadData()
     })
}
```

Take A Look :

[RefreshControlDemo](https://www.dropbox.com/s/trrd2nfrxmymue2/RefreshControlDemo.zip?dl=0) [Swift 3 Xcode 8]

Comment: If i do as you say,
Remove the following code at your setupView()
jobTableView.addSubview(refreshControl) 

then, UiRefresh control will not be in view hierarchy . You are asking me to remove the feature that has problem, rather than solving the problem.

Comment: @SamipShah, sorry my bad,I thought you are using UITableViewController.I uploaded the sample.You might want to check.There is no need to set contentOffset of refreshControl to zero.Please use Legacy Swift Version to "yes" when you build this project.

Comment: Done editing. If you see this demo project, you might understand that there is no need to set Offset = zero to hide UIRefreshControl because it automatically done it self at endRefreshing. You might need to check your code again.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uirefreshcontrol/1624848-endrefreshing

Comment: I have seen the cause of the error, please take a look at my edited answer. You must call endRefreshing before reloading the Table. If not, after reloading the table, it might bring some buggy to UIRefreshControl. Hope this help. Refer to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27280544/uirefreshcontroller-ending-animation-issue

Comment: Due to my limited reputation in stackOverFlow , I am commenting from my friends account.(Samip Shah). You are right in your own way, but for this particular condition, it didn't worked. 
It might be because of the alamofire, in success block the end refreshing code works perfectly.But in Fail block of alamofire, the same code does't make the refresh control go back to initial position,it gets stuck on upper part of table view.
I even removed the part that says reload table .still didn't work. making the content offset of table made the refresh control hide.

Comment: Hmmm,that is pretty strange.I will take a look at Alamofire with custom Rest Service.Anyway, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

i find same problem

if another use  `self.refresh.endRefreshing()` not work

I introduce this code -> `UIRefreshControl().endRefreshing()` replace in state `self.refresh.endRefreshing()`

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {

       UIRefreshControl().endRefreshing()
       self.yourTableView.contentOffset = CGPoint.zero

 }
```

thank you